# How to assign permission to different user in laravel4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have assigned roles to users such as teamleader and project manager.
Now I want that team leader can create team and project manager can manage project

My controller-

```
    $roles=User::find($id)->roles()->get();
    $role2=array();
    foreach($roles as $rolesss) {
        $role2[] = $rolesss->name;

    }
    Log::info('coming',$role2);

    if(in_array('teamleader',$role2) &&  in_array('projectmanager',$role2) )
    {
return 'djfdj';}
   elseif(in_array('teamleader',$role2))
    {
        return 'team';
    }
    elseif(in_array('projectmanager',$role2))
{
return 'project';}
```

Now my user model

```
         public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongstoMany('Role','user_roles','user_id', 'role_id');
}

public function hasRole($check)
{
    return in_array($check, array_fetch($this->roles->toArray(), 'name'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For permission and role based work there is a package for laravel named sentinel which is very much useful and easy to implement.

github link is:

https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel

For documentation you can visit following link:

https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0